# Получить число из диапазона a:b не входящее в список

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Мне необходимо получить число в определенном диапазоне, например от 0 до 1000, которого нет в определенном списке.

Все что я придумал это вот такую рекурсивную функцию для маленького списка занятых чисел:

```
def get_number(banned_numbers):
    number = random.randint(1,1000)
    if number in banned_numbers:
        return get_number(banned_numbers)
    return number
```

Так что при заполнении списка она должна работать в разы медленнее и выдавать ошибки.

Я плохо разбираюсь в подобных алгоритмах, поэтому заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: `random.choice(tuple(set(range(1, 1001)) - set(banned_numbers)))`

Comment: А не состоит ли реальная задача в том, чтобы генерировать числа без повторов?

Answer (score 0):

Уже в комментариях ответили:

```
random.choice(tuple(set(range(1, 1001)) - set(banned_numbers)))
```

Спасибо

Comment: И `при заполнении списка` вы постоянно обновляете `set(banned_numbers)`